# Is a postgres index updated automatically?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In my pgAdmin 3 I have a option in the context menu on index that says `update`. Does this mean an index is not updated automatically on every insert? If that is the case, how can I configure it to update itself?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you care to add your comment as an answer so that I can mark my question as answered?

Comment: There is no `update` menu item in the contex menu. Perhaps you mean `refresh`, which concerns the refreshment of the tree view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are updated automatically [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-intro.html)

> Once an index is created, no further intervention is required: the system will update the index when the table is modified

As I don't use pgAdmin, I don't know what that "Update" item is supposed to do.